# Select and filter related models

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    # ...

class Result(models.Model):
    # ...
    competition = ForeignKey(Competition, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='individual_results',
                             related_query_name='individual_results')
    athlete = ForeignKey(Athlete, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Athlete(models.Model):
    # ...
```

What I'd like to do is create an overview for each athlete and display the results for that athlete grouped by competition.

Tried something like this:

```
athlete = Athlete.objects.get(pk=1)
competitions = Competition.objects
                .prefetch_related('individual_results')
                .filter(individual_results__athlete=athlete)
```

But when I do `competition.indvidual_results.all` in a template, it displays all results from the competition and not only the ones for that athlete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.filter(..)` does *not* filter the related managers. It can be used to filter when you aggregate, but not items in the prefetch manager.

You can however use a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects), like:

```
results = Result.objects.filter(athlete_id=1)
competitions = Competition.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('individual_results', queryset=results, to_attr='athlete_results')
)
```

Now the individual results for the athlete with `id=1`, are stored in an attribute `athlete_results` in the `Competition`s that arise from this queryset.